# The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions when using getValue within loop

Tags: exception, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an google sheet app script that I am running manually. When executing the clearForecast() function, I receive the following exception:

> Exception: The coordinates of the target range are outside the
>   dimensions of the sheet. (line 30, file "Code")

```
sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function clearForecast(){
  moveProjectionActions();
  // sh.getRange("forecast!A2:D").clearContent();

}

function moveProjectionActions() {
  var locSheets = ["clt","chi","kan","mil","nnj","nva","nyc","sfl","uny"];

  for (var i = 0; i < locSheets.length; i++) {
    friendlyName = locSheets[i];

    // the numComments line below is line 30.
    numComments = sh.getSheetByName(friendlyName).getRange("Y13").getValue();

    if (numComments > 0) {
      locValues = sh.getSheetByName(friendlyName).getRange('U6:Y12').getValues();

      shFrom = friendlyName + "!U6:Y12";
      var source = sh.getRange(shFrom);
      var destSheet = sh.getSheetByName("forecast_log");

      var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
      source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});

      sh.getSheetByName(friendlyName).getRange('X6:Y12').clearContent();
    }  
  }
}
```

The formula in the Y13 cell is:

> =counta(X6:X12)

This exception occurs ONLY when there is a number greater than 0. If it's 0, or text, all is well.

Strangely, I made another function:

```
function testFunc() {
  num_comments = sh.getSheetByName("clt").getRange("Y13").getValue();
}
```

When this is executed, no exception. I have been hours trying to get to the bottom of this and any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Spot on. Or close. I had a formula to the right of the destination cells. Thank you so much!

Comment: Did your issue get solved? If that's the case, and the solution was not the one in my answer, would you consider posting an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception was the result of a formula existing in the right-hand most cells within the range I was attempting to write to.

Once removed, it worked as expected.

Comment: Not sure if I understand how a formula can cause this error. This error basically means the destination range you want to copy to does not completely exist (some of its row or columns do not exist). Could you please expand on that?

Comment: Sure. The destination sheet was structured to populate the left-hand most cells w/ data from the script. the right-hand most cells contained formulas to combine data from two cells to the left. any cells w/ data in rows being updated resulted in an error. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function testFunc() {
  var locSheets = ["clt","chi","kan","mil","nnj","nva","nyc","sfl","uny"];
  for (var i = 0; i < locSheets.length; i++) {
    try {
    var numComments = sh.getSheetByName(locSheets[i]).getRange("Y13").getValue();
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(locSheets[i] + ', ' + locSheets[i].getMaxRows() + ', ' +  locSheets[i].getMaxColumns());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

You are trying to copy the source range to a destination range that does not exist.

#### Explanation:

Let's look at what the error says:

> The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet.

The target range, in this case, refers to `destRange`, to which you want to copy `source` via [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)). This target range, the error says, falls outside the dimensions of the destination sheet. So, let's look at how was the target range defined:

```js
destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
```

Here, the target range is defined as the first cell of the first row after the last row with content (`destSheet.getLastRow() + 1`). The fact that you are getting an error there means the last row with content (`destSheet.getLastRow()`) is also the last row in the sheet (there are no empty rows after the last row with content).

#### Solution:

Before copying the range, insert a blank row to the destination sheet to make sure there is an empty row at the end of the sheet. You could use [insertRowAfter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRowAfter(Integer)), for example, just before `copyTo`:

```js
destSheet.insertRowAfter(destSheet.getLastRow());
source.copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
```

#### Note:

- If `Y13` is not a positive number, no exception occurs because the code never enters the `if` block: `if (numComments > 0) { ... }`.